# edebug-defun at compile-time or at eval-buffer time?

Tags: edebug

While I am developing some elisp package I find myself `edebug-defun`'ing the same critical functions `foo-some-mess` and `bar-more` everytime I modify them, or everytime I load the code after compiling.

Is there a way to tell emacs *once and for all* that these two functions must be stepped through with `edebug`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to do this by surrounding definitions of function you want to instrument with `(edebug-all-defs)`.

```el
(edebug-all-defs)

;; this one is instrumented
(defun foo ()
  (bar))

;; this one is, too
(defun bar ()
  (message "hi!"))

(edebug-all-defs)

;; this one is not
(defun baz ()
  (bar))
```

Now `foo` and `bar` are instrumented, and `baz` is not.

I found this by pressing `C-h k C-M-x` and reading the doc. string, which pointed me to `edebug-all-defs`. Its documentation string says this:

> `edebug-all-defs` is a variable defined in `edebug.el`.
>   Its value is nil
>
> Documentation:
>
> If non-nil, evaluating defining forms instruments for Edebug.
>   This applies to `eval-defun`, `eval-region`, `eval-buffer`, and
>   `eval-current-buffer`.  `eval-region` is also called by
>   `eval-last-sexp`, and `eval-print-last-sexp`.
>
> You can use the command `edebug-all-defs` to toggle the value of this
>   variable.  You may wish to make it local to each buffer with
>   `(make-local-variable 'edebug-all-defs)` in your
>   `emacs-lisp-mode-hook`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to be just what I need. I'll try it before accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is: if it hurts, don't do that.

More specifically, don't "compile + load" the code, but edit the code directly in the Emacs where you perform the tests, and after changing the code just do `C-u C-M-x` or `C-M-x` (according to whether the changed code should be stepped or not).